# Console.Write in .NET GUI Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In a C# .NET GUI Application. I also need the console in the background for some tasks. Basically, I'm using a Thrid Party library for some processing (takes lot of time) which writes its intermediate results to console. This processing is a computationally time taking task. So, I'm assigning this task to backgroundworker. I mean background worker calls these library functions.  But problem is there is no way for me to show the user status of computation, because I don't have source of the library. I was hoping Console will be shown. But surprisingly `Console.WriteLine` doesn't seem to work. I mean, there isn't any console window shown. How come?

**EDIT:**

I tried setting application type = console. But there seems to be a problem. Only, main thread is able to access the console. Only `Console.WriteLine`s executed by main (Application) thread are displayed on console. `Console.WriteLine`s executed by other (BackgroundWorker)threads of the GUI, the output is not shown. I need console only for Background workers. I mean, When background worker starts, console starts & when it ends console will be off.

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what you want: How to hide the console window : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160338/how-to-hide-console-after-creating-form-in-console-application

Answer (score 2):

Create your own console window and use the ***Console.SetOut(myTextWriter);*** method to read anything written to the console.

Comment: Well, How can I use this, if I'm not the one who is writing to console? I said, third party application is writing to console & I don't have source to it.

Comment: If the third-party library is a .NET assembly and uses `Console.Out` this will let you grab whatever it is printing and display it in your own window.  If it's a native DLL that you p/invoke, `Console.SetOut` won't be effective.

Answer (score 2):

Set your application type to "Console Application".  Console applications can also create GUI windows with no problem, and write to the console at the same time.

If you don't have control of the main application, and you want to make sure that a console is shown, you can p/invoke [`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944.aspx) ([signature here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/AllocConsole.html)).

This isn't the same as being a console application though, your application will always get a separate console window, which might be surprising to someone who launched it from a command prompt window.  You can work around that with [`AttachConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952.aspx) (s[ignature and example here](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/AttachConsole.html)) but shell redirection of the output still won't work.  That's why I suggest setting the application subsystem to console if you can.

Comment: This is surprising! Now, this raises the question "How Console & GUI Applications are different?". So far, I thought GUI application class inherits from `Form` and Console applications don't. Is there anything more to this?

Comment: GUI application class doesn't inherit from `Form`.  In a GUI application your main function creates an instance of some class derived from `Form` and calls `Application.Run` (for WinForms, a different but similar function for WPF).  You can call `Application.Run` from a console program as well, and it will show a GUI alongside the console window.

Comment: Here's an explanation, that also shows that a GUI program can be remarked as a console program AFTER it's done building: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/EditBin.aspx

Comment: Also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx which described the linker flags which set the SUBSYSTEM field in the PE header (someone mentioned this header, then deleted their comment for some reason).  Note that `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` is used when *Application does not require a console, probably because it creates its own windows for interaction with the user*.  A `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` application is not required to create windows, and a `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE` application is not prohibited from creatinbg them.  These two options really mean **CONSOLE** and **NOCONSOLE**.

Comment: I also needed this. I tried setting application type = console. But there seems to be a problem. Only, main thread is able to access the console. Only `Console.WriteLine`s executed by main (Application) thread are displayed on console. `Console.WriteLine`s executed by other (BackgroundWorker)threads of the GUI, the output is not shown. I need console only for Background workers. I mean, When background worker starts, console starts & when it ends console will be off.

Answer (score 0):

Followed by @jgauffin, here is the implementation of `Console.SetOut` method.

Create a `TextWriter` inherited class.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleRedirection
{
    public class TextBoxStreamWriter : TextWriter
    {
        TextBox _output = null;

        public TextBoxStreamWriter(TextBox output)
        {
            _output = output;
        }

        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            base.Write(value);
            _output.AppendText(value.ToString()); // When character data is written, append it to the text box.
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }
}
```

And in the Form, code as below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleRedirection
{
    public partial class FormConsole : Form
    {
        // That's our custom TextWriter class
        TextWriter _writer = null;

        public FormConsole()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void FormConsole_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             // Instantiate the writer
             _writer = new TextBoxStreamWriter(txtConsole);
             // Redirect the out Console stream
            Console.SetOut(_writer);

            Console.WriteLine("Now redirecting output to the text box");
        }

        // This is called when the "Say Hello" button is clicked
        private void txtSayHello_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Writing to the Console now causes the text to be displayed in the text box.
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world");
        }
    }
}
```

Original code is from https://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/
You can check the link for cross-thread calls and advanced implementations at comments.