# Console.Write is not working when executed by BackgroundWorker of .NET GUI Application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've a (C#).NET GUI application. Where I need console for displaying some output. The code that (is writing to console) contains `Console.WriteLine` statements is executed by the BackgroundWorker & not the main thread.

Some one suggested,here: [Console.Write in .NET GUI Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385097/console-write-in-net-gui-application/3385142) that making your application type`Console Application`  instead of "Windows Application" will do the job. But this is only working when the Main Thread (GUI thread) is writing to console. More over, I don't need Console to be displayed when application starts. I only want it when background worker begins its work and when its finished, I want console to disappear.

How can display console as required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might want to keep your app as a WinForms app and then use [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [FreeConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683150%28VS.85%29.aspx) to create and remove the console as needed.

Since you only want to use it from the worker thread, I think it might work if you create it in the worker thread.

Please note, I haven't tried the above, so I'm not sure if it would work or not.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your class:

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern bool FreeConsole();
```

Now, In your backgroundWorker.

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(Object obj, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        AllocConsole();
        // do the task of your background worker here here
        FreeConsole();
    }
```